# How to add multiple peers in fabric composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Basic sample networks provided by composer are working on only one peer. How ca we add multiple peers in the network and enroll user to each peer.

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask a question. The context is vague and your research is non-existent.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define your Hyperledger Composer v1. connection profile to include those peers, where-ever they are located.

You need to install Composer runtime onto those 2 peers - using `composer runtime install` command. Then start the network. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.runtime.install.html

Eg. 
`composer runtime install -n my-network -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s adminpw`
then
`composer network start -a mybiznetwork.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s adminpw`

It will have deployed its own chaincode container for the business network.

Obviously, before these commands are executed, you would have to ensure the PeerAdmin's crypto material (ie PeerAdmin in the examples above)  has been imported so as to be recognised by the CA server. Eg. so that you can then install the composer runtime onto a peer using the `composer runtime install` command etc etc.

Comment: thanks Paul. but I have imported peerAdmin crypto material using "composer identity import -p hlfv1 -u PeerAdmin -c /home/suvit/goWork/hyperledgerComposer/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k /home/suvit/goWork/hyperledgerComposer/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/694399af5a1c15d970e43d2e277d3fc182868eec0d7e353c7d7a1b745be35e14_sk" command. Is it correct?

Comment: and tried to run the composer runtime install command then it gives me same error as i mention in above 1st comment ie.certificate sign by unknown authority

Comment: the syntax is correct. It seems to me you haven't actually gone through the Fabric setup to configured the extra peer and to join it to the Fabric network. Composer doesn't do this for you (we just stand up a sample network - Have you got the second peer up and running, has it joined the channel - like would be shown here for our dev setup that you're using? https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/startFabric.sh

Comment: the syntax is correct. It seems to me you haven't actually gone through the Fabric setup to configured the extra peer and to join it to the Fabric network. Composer doesn't do this for you (we just stand up a sample network - Have you got the second peer up and running, has it joined the channel - like would be shown here for our dev setup that you're using? https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/startFabric.sh  and .. (cont'd..)

Comment: ..accompanying Docker YAML file here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/docker-compose.yml. I suggest to also read http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html and once you've added, and configured your extra peer(s), to then add the entries for the correctly resolved peer containers to your connection.json file.

Answer (score 0):

See http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html. Once you have created your own topology you need to configure your connection profiles and identities appropriately using Composer. A connection profile represents a single organisation interacting on a single channel. Of course in fabric you are allowed to submit transactions to other peers in different organisations so that connection profile can contain peers from other organisations but only for transaction submission. If you want to simulate handling of 2 or more organisations then you will need profiles for each organisation.

Comment: I have add 2 peers in the network using cryptogen. But when I trying to deploy .bna file it shows : Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install chaincode. Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")
Command failed